# How to block a Jenkins Slave till another job running on another slave is finished?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

How to block a slave till another job running on another slave is finished?

Labels : Slaves with with matching labels

'server' : S1 & S2

'client' : C1 & C2

Job description : 3 jobs, J1, J2 & J3. J1 runs on 'server' labeled slaves. J2 & J3 run on 'client' labeled slaves. When parent job starts, it triggers J1 on S1, waits till it finishes & then triggers J2 & J3 sequentially on C1.

I want S1 to be free only when J2 & J3 are finished.
Also, if another build is triggered while the first job is running, it should pick S2 & C2

I am using "NodeLabel Parameter Plugin" for slave selection along as of now.
I have been trying to play with Build Blocker plugin, executor counts, etc. but haven't met much success.